# ./azsphere_connect.sh can't connect to device

Tags: azure-sphere

When trying to connect to Azure Sphere using the provided azsphere_connect.sh, we get an error, as below:

> $ sudo ./azsphere_connect.sh -v VERBOSE: Looking for attached Azure
>   Sphere devices VERBOSE: Found attached Azure Sphere device at
>   /dev/ttyUSB2 VERBOSE: Setting up SLIP connection ERROR: Could not
>   establish SLIP connection.

This has been acting like this for a few months. The only workaround I found was to patch net-tools/slattach to support the higher speeds required by Azure Sphere and use that instead.

Answer (score 3):

Currently, the only supported Linux distros are Ubuntu 18.04. Are you seeing this error if you are using Ubuntu as well?

Here's the link to documentation - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure-sphere/install/install-sdk-linux#prerequisites

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have access to a Ubuntu machine to try this out. Still, regular `slattach` from `net-tools` works fine on the same machine; this points to a problem with `azsphere_slattach`